How to clean Hibernate cache or Jpa Repository?
So I removed this attribute called price from my entity class.
But when running my spring-boot server, it still think its still in the table.
My application.properties is configured as such: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update.
I can't use create drop because I got some data in other tables I don't want to re enter
I'd manually delete the column and then every now and then at random runs of my application the column comes back and I'd have to manually delete again, any idea why? and how to fix.

update won't delete columns only add new ones. Don't use the hibernate DDL features to manage your schema (only for tests). Use something proper like liquibase or Flyway to manage your schema.

I know but I delete manually delete the column and it keeps coming back at random times

If it comes back hibernate will see the column, indicating that you are running with old code for some reason. But as stated don't use hibernate to manage your schema that is a bad idea.

@M.Deinum Is there any other way to manage my schema other than hibernate? I am only still fresh in springboot and most tutorials have used hibernate. Are there better alternatives?

You can manage your schema with flyway or other tools. But just put  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate to investigate.

I've added the solutions to my first comment already either something like Liquibase or Flyway are common ways for this.

I'm pretty sure Hibernated doesn't "remember" the domain model between runs.
So, if you still see a column that you removed from your domain model appear in your schema, there are a couple of things going on.

Your domain model still contain the column. Maybe multiple classes are mapped to the same table, maybe there is a inherited entity, which still has the property. How to find it: Search the code basis for the property name.

You have some SQL script running. This could be a plain schema.sql or a Liquibase or Flyway script. Or maybe a script that runs as part of an integration test. Search for the column name or SQL keywords: e.g. create. Search for typical file name suffixes e.g. sql.

You are occasionally running an old version of your application. CI jobs are great at running old branches.

Someone else is doing any of these things.


For the last two some database internal logging could help, like what connections are open to the database. How to do that with your database would depend on the database.

When using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update, Hibernate attempts to update the database schema without deleting any data. This means that it won't automatically drop columns even if they no longer exist in your entity class. As a result, the issue may persist due to the column lingering in the database schema.
Hibernate's schema may be cached or not in sync with the actual database on occasion. To make sure Hibernate reflects the latest state of your entity, either clear any cache (if enabled) or restart the application after making changes.
You can clean the cache at the Application level
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = false


oh okay, I'll try that, thanks

Also restarting doesnt work because I'll manually delete and it will work even after few re runs and then out of no where column will show again. But I'll try the fix you gave:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false

Disabling 2nd level caching will yield nothing and has nothing to do with schema creation.
